# jquery dynamic click not working on checkbox multiseelect plugin

Tags: jquery

I added dynamically new checkbox in dropdown but when I click on new checkbox that checkbox value not showing in dropdown.
It is using addeventlister change event thats why its not clickable.I tried onclick event but it is not working.
Please Help me

I am using this multiselect plugin.
https://github.com/mneofit/multiselect

Here is mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pure js multiselect demo</title>

    <link href="styles/multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="multiselect.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* example of setting the width for multiselect */
        #testSelect1_multiSelect {
            width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="inline_content">
<p>Condesnsing Unit</p>
    <form class="type">
        <input type="radio" name="condesnsing_type" checked="checked" value="208-230/1/60">208-230/1/60</input>
        <input type="radio" name="condesnsing_type" value="460/3/60">460/3/60</input>
    </form>
</div>
<select id='testSelect1' multiple>
    <option value='1'>Item 1</option>
    <option value='2' selected>Item 2</option>
    <option value='3' selected>Item 3</option>
    <option value='4'>Item 4</option>
    <option value='5'>Item 5</option>
</select>

<div>
    <button class="test">add</button>
    <button onclick="disable()">Disable</button>
</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#inline_content input[name='condesnsing_type']").change(function(){

    if($('input:radio[name=condesnsing_type]:checked').val() == "460/3/60"){
    //
        addNewOptionInDropdown();
                }
});

//custom
function addNewOptionInDropdown(){
   var item = 'Item 6';
            var myOptionsGreen = [{name:item, value:'6'}];
            var mySelect = $('#testSelect1');
            $.each(myOptionsGreen, function(index, value) {
            
                mySelect.append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
                //var addliElement = '<li style="display: block;"><label><input class="multiselect-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-val="'+value.value+'" data-multiselect-element="{"id":"'+value.value+'","index":5,"text":"'+value.name+'","selected":true,"selectElement":{},"multiselectElement":{}}"><span class="multiselect-text">'+value.name+'</span></label></li>';
                var addliElement = '<li style="display: block;"><label><input class="multiselect-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-val="6" data-multiselect-element="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;index&quot;:5,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Item 6&quot;,&quot;selected&quot;:false,&quot;selectElement&quot;:{},&quot;multiselectElement&quot;:{}}"><span class="multiselect-text">Item 6</span></label></li>';
                
                $('#testSelect1_itemList ul').append(addliElement);

            });
            

}

</script>
<script>

        

        document.multiselect('#testSelect1').setCheckBoxClick("checkboxAll", function(target, args) {
            console.log("Checkbox 'Select All' was clicked and got value ", args.checked);
        })
        .setCheckBoxClick("1", function(target, args) {
            console.log("Checkbox for item with value '1' was clicked and got value ", args.checked);
        });

    function enable() {
        document.multiselect('#testSelect1').setIsEnabled(true);
    }

    function disable() {
        document.multiselect('#testSelect1').setIsEnabled(false);
    }
</script>
</body>
```

check below code in js file

```
e.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
                self._onCheckBoxChange(e, self, event);
            });
```

**Multiselect.min.js**

```
if (!m_helper) {
    var m_helper = {
        removeNode: function (id) {
            var el = document.getElementById(id);
            if (el) {
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
            }
        },
        insertAfter: function (item, target) {
            var parent = target.parentNode;
            if (target.nextElementSibling) {
                parent.insertBefore(item, target.nextElementSibling);
            } else {
                parent.appendChild(item);
            }
        },
        hide: function (element) {
            element.style.display = "none";
        },
        hideAll: function (array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                this.hide(array[i]);
            }
        },
        show: function (element) {
            element.style.display = "block";
        },
        showAll: function (array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                this.show(array[i]);
            }
        },
        parent: function (element, id) {
            var parent = element.parentElement;
            while (parent && parent.tagName != "BODY") {
                if (parent.id == id) {
                    return parent;
                }
                parent = parent.parentElement;
            }
            return null;
        },
        create: function (data) {
            var result = document.createElement(data.tag);
            if (data.id) {
                result.id = data.id;
            }
            if (data.class) {
                result.className = data.class;
            }
            if (data.attributes) {
                for (var prop in data.attributes) {
                    result.setAttribute(prop, data.attributes[prop]);
                }
            }
            if (data.data) {
                for (var prop in data.data) {
                    result.dataset[prop] = data.data[prop];
                }
            }
            return result;
        },
        div: function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                data = new Object();
            }
            data.tag = "div";
            return this.create(data);
        },
        label: function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                data = new Object();
            }
            data.tag = "label";
            return this.create(data);
        },
        textField: function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                data = new Object();
            }
            data.tag = "input";
            if (!data.attributes) data.attributes = new Object();
            data.attributes.type = "text";
            return this.create(data);
        },
        checkbox: function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                data = new Object();
            }
            data.tag = "input";
            if (!data.attributes) data.attributes = new Object();
            data.attributes.type = "checkbox";
            return this.create(data);
        },
        each: function (array, handler) {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                handler(array[i]);
            }
        },
        setActive: function (element) {
            element.classList.add("active");
        },
        setUnactive: function (element) {
            element.classList.remove("active");
        },
        select: function (element) {
            element.selected = !0;
            element.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
        },
        deselect: function (element) {
            element.selected = !1;
            element.removeAttribute("selected");
        },
        check: function (element) {
            element.checked = !0;
        },
        uncheck: function (element) {
            element.checked = !1;
        },
        click: function (element) {
            if (element.fireEvent) {
                el.fireEvent("onclick");
            } else {
                var evObj = document.createEvent("Events");
                evObj.initEvent("click", !0, !1);
                element.dispatchEvent(evObj);
            }
        },
        setDisabled: function (element, value) {
            element.disabled = value;
        },
    };
}
function Multiselect(item, opts) {
    if ((typeof $ != "undefined" && !$(item).is("select")) || (typeof $ == "undefined" && item.tagName != "SELECT")) {
        throw "Multiselect: passed object must be a select";
    }
    if ((typeof $ != "undefined" && !$(item).attr("multiple")) || (typeof $ == "undefined" && !item.hasAttribute("multiple"))) {
        throw "Multiselect: passed object should contain 'multiple' attribute";
    }
    this._item = item;
    this._createUI();
    this._appendEvents();
    this._initSelectedFields();
    this._initIsEnabled();
}
Multiselect.prototype = {
    _createUI: function () {
        m_helper.removeNode(this._getIdentifier());
        var wrapper = this._createWrapper();
        m_helper.insertAfter(wrapper, this._item);
        wrapper.appendChild(this._createInputField());
        wrapper.appendChild(this._createItemList());
        m_helper.hide(this._item);
    },
    _createWrapper: function () {
        var result = document.createElement("div");
        result.className = "multiselect-wrapper";
        result.id = this._getIdentifier();
        return result;
    },
    _createInputField: function () {
        var input = m_helper.textField({ id: this._getInputFieldIdentifier(), class: "multiselect-input", attributes: { autocomplete: "off" } }),
            label = m_helper.label({ id: this._getInputBadgeIdentifier(), class: "multiselect-count", attributes: { for: this._getInputFieldIdentifier() } }),
            dropDownArrow = m_helper.label({ class: "multiselect-dropdown-arrow", attributes: { for: this._getInputFieldIdentifier() } }),
            result = m_helper.div({ class: "multiselect-input-div" });
        label.style.visibility = "hidden";
        label.innerHTML = 0;
        result.appendChild(input);
        result.appendChild(label);
        result.appendChild(dropDownArrow);
        return result;
    },
    _createItemList: function () {
        var list = m_helper.create({ tag: "ul" });
        var self = this;
        m_helper.each(this._getItems(this._item), function (e) {
            var insertItem = self._createItem("li", e.id, e.text, e.selected);
            list.appendChild(insertItem);
            var checkBox = insertItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
            e.multiselectElement = checkBox;
            checkBox.dataset.multiselectElement = JSON.stringify(e);
        });
        var selectAll = this._createItem("span", -1, "Select all");
        var result = m_helper.div({ id: this._getItemListIdentifier(), class: "multiselect-list" });
        result.appendChild(selectAll);
        result.appendChild(m_helper.create({ tag: "hr" }));
        result.appendChild(list);
        return result;
    },
    _createItem: function (wrapper, value, text, selected) {
        var checkBox = m_helper.checkbox({ class: "multiselect-checkbox", data: { val: value } }),
            textBox = m_helper.create({ tag: "span", class: "multiselect-text" }),
            result = m_helper.create({ tag: wrapper }),
            label = m_helper.label();
        textBox.className = "multiselect-text";
        textBox.innerHTML = text;
        label.appendChild(checkBox);
        label.appendChild(textBox);
        result.appendChild(label);
        return result;
    },
    _initSelectedFields: function () {
        var itemResult = this._getItems().filter(function (obj) {
            return obj.selected;
        });
        if (itemResult.length != 0) {
            var self = this;
            m_helper.each(itemResult, function (e) {
                self.select(e.id);
            });
        }
        this._hideList(this);
    },
    _initIsEnabled: function () {
        this.setIsEnabled(!this._item.disabled);
    },
    destroy() {
        m_helper.removeNode(this._getIdentifier());
        m_helper.show(this._item);
        var index = window.multiselects._items.indexOf(this._item);
        if (index > -1) {
            window.multiselects._items.splice(index, 1);
            window.multiselects.splice(index, 1);
        }
    },
    select: function (val) {
        this._toggle(val, !0);
    },
    deselect: function (val) {
        this._toggle(val, !1);
    },
    setIsEnabled(isEnabled) {
        if (this._isEnabled === isEnabled) return;
        var wrapperItem = document.getElementById(this._getIdentifier());
        if (isEnabled) {
            wrapperItem.classList.remove("disabled");
        } else {
            wrapperItem.classList.add("disabled");
        }
        m_helper.setDisabled(this._item, !isEnabled);
        m_helper.setDisabled(document.getElementById(this._getInputFieldIdentifier()), !isEnabled);
        this._isEnabled = isEnabled;
    },
    _toggle: function (val, setCheck) {
        var self = this;
        if (val) {
            m_helper.each(document.getElementById(this._getIdentifier()).querySelectorAll(".multiselect-checkbox"), function (e) {
                if (e.dataset.val == val) {
                    if (setCheck && !e.checked) {
                        m_helper.check(e);
                        self._onCheckBoxChange(e, self);
                    } else if (!setCheck && e.checked) {
                        m_helper.uncheck(e);
                        self._onCheckBoxChange(e, self);
                    }
                }
            });
            self._updateText(self);
        }
    },
    selectAll: function (val) {
        var selectAllChkBox = document.querySelector("#" + this._getIdentifier() + " .multiselect-checkbox");
        m_helper.check(selectAllChkBox);
        this._onCheckBoxChange(selectAllChkBox, this);
        this._updateText(this);
    },
    deselectAll: function () {
        var selectAllChkBox = document.querySelector("#" + this._getIdentifier() + " .multiselect-checkbox");
        m_helper.uncheck(selectAllChkBox);
        this._onCheckBoxChange(selectAllChkBox, this);
        this._updateText(this);
    },
    _checkboxClickEvents: {},
    setCheckBoxClick(id, handler) {
        if (typeof handler === "function") {
            this._checkboxClickEvents[id] = handler;
        } else {
            console.error("Checkbox click handler for checkbox value=" + id + " is not a function");
        }
        return this;
    },
    _appendEvents: function () {
        var self = this;
        document.getElementById(self._getInputFieldIdentifier()).addEventListener("focus", function (event) {
            self._showList(self);
            document.getElementById(self._getInputFieldIdentifier()).value = "";
            m_helper.each(window.multiselects, function (e) {
                if (document.getElementById(e._getItemListIdentifier()).offsetParent && m_helper.parent(event.target, e._getIdentifier())) {
                    e._hideList(self);
                }
            });
        });
        document.getElementById(self._getInputFieldIdentifier()).addEventListener("click", function () {
            self._showList(self);
            document.getElementById(self._getInputFieldIdentifier()).value = "";
        });
        document.getElementById(self._getIdentifier()).addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            event = event || window.event;
            var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
            if (m_helper.parent(target, self._getIdentifier())) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
        document.getElementById(self._getItemListIdentifier()).addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
            self._showList(self);
        });
        m_helper.each(document.getElementById(self._getIdentifier()).querySelectorAll(".multiselect-checkbox"), function (e) {
            e.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
                self._onCheckBoxChange(e, self, event);
            });
        });
        var onInput = function () {
            var text = this.value.toLowerCase();
            if (!text || text == "") {
                m_helper.show(document.querySelector("#" + self._getItemListIdentifier() + " > span"));
                m_helper.show(document.querySelector("#" + self._getItemListIdentifier() + " > hr"));
                m_helper.showAll(document.querySelectorAll("#" + self._getItemListIdentifier() + " li"));
            } else {
                m_helper.hide(document.querySelector("#" + self._getItemListIdentifier() + " > span"));
                m_helper.hide(document.querySelector("#" + self._getItemListIdentifier() + " > hr"));
                var array = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("#" + self._getItemListIdentifier() + " li span"), function (obj) {
                    return obj.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1;
                });
                m_helper.hideAll(document.querySelectorAll("#" + self._getItemListIdentifier() + " li"));
                m_helper.each(array, function (e) {
                    m_helper.show(e.parentElement.parentElement);
                });
            }
        };
        document.getElementById(self._getInputFieldIdentifier()).addEventListener("propertychange", onInput);
        document.getElementById(self._getInputFieldIdentifier()).addEventListener("input", onInput);
    },
    _onCheckBoxChange: function (checkbox, self, event) {
        if (!checkbox.dataset.multiselectElement) {
            var checkedState = self._performSelectAll(checkbox, self);
            if (typeof self._checkboxClickEvents.checkboxAll === "function") {
                self._checkboxClickEvents.checkboxAll(checkbox, { checked: checkedState });
            }
        } else {
            var checkedState = self._performSelectItem(checkbox, self);
            if (typeof self._checkboxClickEvents[checkedState.id] === "function") {
                self._checkboxClickEvents[checkedState.id](checkbox, checkedState);
            }
            self._updateSelectAll(self);
        }
        self._forceUpdate();
    },
    _performSelectItem: function (checkbox, self) {
        var item = JSON.parse(checkbox.dataset.multiselectElement);
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            self._itemCounter++;
            m_helper.select(this._item.options[item.index]);
            m_helper.setActive(checkbox.parentElement.parentElement);
            return { id: item.id, checked: !0 };
        }
        self._itemCounter--;
        m_helper.deselect(this._item.options[item.index]);
        m_helper.setUnactive(checkbox.parentElement.parentElement);
        return { id: item.id, checked: !1 };
    },
    _performSelectAll: function (checkbox, self) {
        var items = self._getItems();
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            self._itemCounter = items.length;
            m_helper.each(items, function (e) {
                m_helper.setActive(e.multiselectElement.parentElement.parentElement);
                m_helper.select(self._item.options[e.index]);
                m_helper.check(e.multiselectElement);
            });
            return !0;
        }
        self._itemCounter = 0;
        m_helper.each(items, function (e) {
            e.multiselectElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove("active");
            m_helper.deselect(self._item.options[e.index]);
            m_helper.uncheck(e.multiselectElement);
        });
        return !1;
    },
    _updateSelectAll: function (self) {
        var allChkBox = document.getElementById(self._getItemListIdentifier()).querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
        if (self._itemCounter == self._getItems().length) {
            allChkBox.checked = !0;
        } else if (allChkBox.checked) {
            allChkBox.checked = !1;
        }
    },
    _hideList: function (context, event) {
        m_helper.setUnactive(document.getElementById(context._getItemListIdentifier()));
        m_helper.show(document.getElementById(context._getItemListIdentifier()).querySelector("span"));
        m_helper.show(document.getElementById(context._getItemListIdentifier()).querySelector("hr"));
        m_helper.showAll(document.getElementById(context._getItemListIdentifier()).querySelectorAll("li"));
        context._updateText(context);
        if (event) event.stopPropagation();
    },
    _updateText: function (context) {
        var activeItems = document.getElementById(context._getItemListIdentifier()).querySelectorAll("ul .active");
        if (activeItems.length > 0) {
            var val = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < (activeItems.length < 5 ? activeItems.length : 5); i++) {
                val += activeItems[i].innerText + ", ";
            }
            val = val.substr(0, val.length - 2);
            if (val.length > 20) {
                val = val.substr(0, 17) + "...";
            }
        }
        if (activeItems.length == document.getElementById(context._getItemListIdentifier()).querySelectorAll("ul li").length) {
            val = "All selected";
        }
        document.getElementById(context._getInputFieldIdentifier()).value = val ? val : "";
    },
    _showList: function (context) {
        m_helper.setActive(document.getElementById(context._getItemListIdentifier()));
    },
    _forceUpdate: function () {
        var badge = document.getElementById(this._getInputBadgeIdentifier());
        badge.style.visibility = "hidden";
        if (this._itemCounter != 0) {
            badge.innerHTML = this._itemCounter;
            badge.style.visibility = "visible";
            var ddArrow = badge.nextElementSibling;
            if (this._itemCounter < 10) {
                badge.style.left = "-45px";
                ddArrow.style.marginLeft = "-42px";
            } else if (this._itemCounter < 100) {
                badge.style.left = "-50px";
                ddArrow.style.marginLeft = "-47px";
            } else if (this._itemCounter < 1000) {
                badge.style.left = "-55px";
                ddArrow.style.marginLeft = "-52px";
            } else if (this._itemCounter < 10000) {
                badge.style.left = "-60px";
                ddArrow.style.marginLeft = "-57px";
            }
        }
    },
    _items: undefined,
    _itemCounter: 0,
    _isEnabled: !0,
    _getItems: function () {
        if (this._items == undefined) {
            var result = [];
            var opts = this._item.options;
            for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
                var insertItem = { id: opts[i].value, index: i, text: opts[i].innerHTML, selected: !!opts[i].selected, selectElement: opts[i] };
                result.push(insertItem);
            }
            this._items = result;
        }
        return this._items;
    },
    _getItemUniqueIdentifier: function () {
        var id = this._item.getAttribute("id"),
            name = this._item.getAttribute("name");
        if (!(id || name)) {
            throw "Multiselect: object does not contain any identifier (id or name)";
        }
        return id ? id : name;
    },
    _getIdentifier: function () {
        return this._getItemUniqueIdentifier() + "_multiSelect";
    },
    _getInputFieldIdentifier: function () {
        return this._getItemUniqueIdentifier() + "_input";
    },
    _getItemListIdentifier: function () {
        return this._getItemUniqueIdentifier() + "_itemList";
    },
    _getInputBadgeIdentifier: function () {
        return this._getItemUniqueIdentifier() + "_inputCount";
    },
};
window.multiselects = [];
if (typeof $ != "undefined") {
    $.fn.multiselect = function () {
        var res = [];
        if (!window.multiselects._items) {
            window.multiselects._items = [];
        }
        if (this.length != 0) {
            $(this).each(function (i, e) {
                var index = window.multiselects._items.indexOf(e);
                if (index == -1) {
                    var inputItem = new Multiselect(e);
                    window.multiselects.push(inputItem);
                    window.multiselects._items.push(e);
                    res.push(inputItem);
                } else {
                    res.push(window.multiselects[index]);
                }
            });
        }
        return res.length == 1 ? res[0] : $(res);
    };
    $(document).click(function (event) {
        hideMultiselects(event);
    });
} else {
    document.multiselect = function (selector) {
        var res = [];
        if (!window.multiselects._items) {
            window.multiselects._items = [];
        }
        m_helper.each(document.querySelectorAll(selector), function (e) {
            var index = window.multiselects._items.indexOf(e);
            if (index == -1) {
                var inputItem = new Multiselect(e);
                window.multiselects.push(inputItem);
                window.multiselects._items.push(e);
                res.push(inputItem);
            } else {
                res.push(window.multiselects[index]);
            }
        });
        return res.length == 1 ? res[0] : res;
    };
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        hideMultiselects(event);
    };
}
function hideMultiselects(event) {
    m_helper.each(window.multiselects, function (e) {
        if (document.getElementById(e._getItemListIdentifier()).offsetParent && !m_helper.parent(event.target, e._getIdentifier())) {
            e._hideList(e, event);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you click new checkbox value not showing in dropdown input Because you already `set max limit text` so only two checkbox value under your condition you can **remove IF condition** for `_updateText: function (context)` and show your output

> Remove this if condition for **multiselect.min.js** file

```
val = val.substr(0, val.length - 2);
if (val.length > 20) {
    val = val.substr(0, 17) + '...'
}
```

this condition te set fix char display.

Comment: I think you did not check plugin properly but I added checkbox in dropdown but when I click checkbox that checkbox value not showing in in dropdown if I create dynamic checkbox element bcoz this plugin using click event rather than onclick event